# Recursive function to find the smallest number divisible by three numbers simultaneously

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to find the smallest integer that is divisible by 2, 3, and 5 through a recursive function as follows:

```
def recursiva(n):

    lista = []
    if(n%2==0 and n%3==0 and n%10==0):
        lista.append(n)

    n = n - 1
    recursiva(n)

    return min(lista)

recursiva(100)
```

But even for small numbers like 100 I am having stack overflow, as seen in the error message:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I wonder:

- What am I doing wrong?
- Is there any way, instead of passing a fixed value per parameter, to
  make the function look for the smallest number divisible by 2,3 and 5
  within the set of integers?

Comment: Your function doesn’t stop recurring when n goes below 1.

Comment: also you are not saving the result of your recursive call

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, before calling `recursiva()` again, check if *n* is equal or less than 0 (`n<=0`). Without a condition, it will not stop, and will loop infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

In a recursive function you need to have at least 2 possible return statements, 1 where some end condition is met and the answer is returned and 1 where what is returned is new call to the function with some modified input.

Additionally for your problem you need a method of saving the results of the previous calls somewhere. You might consider passing the list of successful calls as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I got it like this:

```
def recursiva(n = 1):
    if (n%2==0 and n%3==0 and n%10==0):
        return n
    else:
        return recursiva(n+1)
recursiva()
```